# get DB records using AJAX in Laravel - EDITED

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to make that when a user types a postal code in an entry to fill in their address, it calls the postal codes table and automatically fills in the province and city.

I am using jquery, with the keyup method to get the value. I would like to know how I have to do so that with AJAX, it gives me these values.

```
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label>Localidad</label>
            <input type="text" name="localidad" id="localidad" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label>Provincia</label>
            <input type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label>Código postal</label>
            <input type="text" name="codigo_postal" class="form-control" id="codigo_postal" maxlength="5" required>
        </div>
    </div>


$(document).ready(function () {
    var codigo_postal = $('#codigo_postal');
    var localidad = $('#localidad');
    var provincia = $('#provincia');
    codigo_postal.keyup(function () {
        var value = codigo_postal.val();
        if (value.length == 5) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'facturacion/guardar/' + value,
            }).done(function (res) {
                alert(res);
            });
        }



    });

});
```

My table:

[image]

My route:

use App\PostalCode;

```
Route::get('facturacion/guardar/{codigo_postal}', function($codigo_postal) {
    $cp = Categoria::where('codigo_postal', $codigo_postal)->first();
    $postal_code = $cp->codigo_postal;
    return response(['estado' => true,
        'postal_code' => $postal_code]);
})->name('postal_code.get');
```

Response:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a request and response (debug view)?

Comment: yep check edit now